# TouchableOpacity not being detected in ReactNatve tests using Anzyme and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

My test is failing because it is not finding TouchableOpacity While testing. What Am I doing wrong?
Below are Test results, Component file, testing file

> Results
>       expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

```
Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received object: {}
```

> src/component/button.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

const Button = props => {
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>{props.label}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>;
};
```

Button.displayName = "Button";
export default Button;

> **tests**/button.test.js

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
// button.js
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Button from "../src/components/Button";

describe("Rendering", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Button label="Submit" />);
  });
  // Can we have clickable object
  it("Should render a <TouchableOpacity />", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("TouchableOpacity")).toHaveLength(1);
  });=
});
```